# Load external ViewModel and template for Knockout component

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, requirejs

**I'm trying to load the template to the viewmodel for a knockout component using require.js, but so far unsuccessful.**

**index.html (view)**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-main="assets/js/app" src="assets/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table_n></table_n>
</body>
```

**menu.html (Template)**

```
<table class="table table- bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align=center width=60 style="display: none">Código</th>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Ordem</th>
            <th>Imagem url</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: ListaUsuarios()}">
        <tr>
            <td style="display: none" data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: titulo"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: descricao"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ordem"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: caminho_imagem"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**menu.js (ViewModel)**

```
define(['knockout', 'knockoutMapping'], function (ko, komap) {
    debugger;
    var self = this;
    debugger;
    self.filter = ko.observable('');
    self.ListaUsuarios = ko.observableArray();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.15.3/api/menus",
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var a = JSON.stringify(result);
            var observableData = komap.fromJS(result);
            var array = observableData();
            self.ListaUsuarios(array);
        }
     });
});
```

**App.js (initializing the knockout parameters)**

```
(function (undefined) {
    'use strict';
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: './', // Raiz
        urlArgs: function (id, url) {
            return (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'v=23';
        }, // Debug Cache
        deps: ['assets/js/base'],
        map: {
            '*': {
                'jQuery': 'jquery'
            }
        },
        paths: {
            // Módulos
            'jquery': 'assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.1.1',
            // Library jQuery
            'knockout': 'assets/js/vendor/knockout-3.4.2',
            'knockoutMapping': 'assets/js/vendor/knockout.mapping-latest',
            // Config
            'start': 'assets/js/start'
        },
        shim: {
            'knockoutMapping': {
                deps: ['knockout']
            }
        },
        waitSeconds: 15
    });
    // Chamando módulo principal para iniciar a aplicação
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        require(['start']);
    });
    requirejs.onError = function (err) {
        console.log(err.requireType);
        console.log('modules: ' + err.requireModules);
        throw err;
    };
}());
```

**base.js (Using jQuery as a module named in RequireJS)**

```
(function () {
    define(['jquery'], function () {
        (function ($) {
            console.info('Verificando Global jQuery...');
            if (typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.document === 'object') {
                if (!!window && !(!!window.$)) {
                    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
                }
                console.log([$, jQuery]);
            }
            var version = $().jquery;
            if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery) {
                console.info('jQuery: ' + version + ' $.fn.jquery: ' + $.fn.jquery);
                return window.jQuery;
            }
        }(jQuery));
    });
}());
```

**start.js (And finally initializing the component)**

```
define(['knockout', 'knockoutMapping'], function (ko, komap) {
    debugger;
    ko.components.register('table_n', {
        viewModel: { require: 'assets/js/component/viewmodel/menu' },
        template: { require: 'text!assets/js/component/templates/menu.html' }
    });

    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

**And I get the many mistakes when i debug on browser**

```
Verificando Global jQuery...
require.js:5 Array(2)
require.js:5 jQuery: 3.1.1 $.fn.jquery: 3.1.1
text.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app.js:36 scripterror
app.js:37 modules: text
app.js:38 Uncaught Error: Script error for "text", needed by: text!assets/js/component/templates/menu.html_unnormalized2
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:5)
makeError @ require.js:5
onScriptError @ require.js:5
app.js:36 require
app.js:37 modules: null
app.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createViewModel' of undefined
    at c (knockout-3.4.2.js?v=23:80)
    at Object.loadViewModel (knockout-3.4.2.js?v=23:82)
    at Object.e [as Nb] (knockout-3.4.2.js?v=23:78)
    at knockout-3.4.2.js?v=23:79
    at Object.execCb (require.js:5)
    at b.check (require.js:5)
    at b.<anonymous> (require.js:5)
    at require.js:5
    at require.js:5
    at each (require.js:5)
c @ knockout-3.4.2.js?v=23:80
loadViewModel @ knockout-3.4.2.js?v=23:82
e @ knockout-3.4.2.js?v=23:78
(anonymous) @ knockout-3.4.2.js?v=23:79
execCb @ require.js:5
check @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
each @ require.js:5
emit @ require.js:5
check @ require.js:5
enable @ require.js:5
init @ require.js:5
h @ require.js:5
completeLoad @ require.js:5
onScriptLoad @ require.js:5
app.js:36 timeout
app.js:37 modules: text!assets/js/component/templates/menu.html_unnormalized2
app.js:38 Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: text!assets/js/component/templates/menu.html_unnormalized2
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at l (require.js:5)
    at require.js:5
makeError @ require.js:5
l @ require.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.js:5
(unknown) XHR Loaded (menus - 200 OK - 971.9319999858271ms - 525B)
```

Comment: Could you show your file structure?

Comment: @Ray, Thanks for your willingness to help, but you can see my error and I posted this as an answer in case someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing some examples about using require, I understood what I was doing wrong:

The index.html files, menu.html (template) are correct, but in the file menu.js (ViewModel) I changed the first line to include the **Jquery library** and looked like this:

```
Define (['jquery', 'knockout', 'knockoutMapping'], function ($, ko, komap) {
```

And at the end of the file after:

```
Self.User List (array);
```

I added the Knockout Applybinds:

```
Ko.applyBindings ();
```

Before it was in the start.js file, however as I'm querying a WebApi with ajax (which is asynchronous), it was activated before ajax finished querying, causing an error.

In the app.js file I added a lib called text.js in paths session, this libreary which can be found in [download here](https://github.com/requirejs/text)
This library is required to load the template, because require by default loads .js files.

And also added the path to the viewmodel menu.js

The modified part of the file was thus

```
  'text': 'assets/js/vendor/text',
  'menu': 'assets/js/component/viewmodel/menu',
```

Remember that this is to be added in session paths after 'knockoutMapping' and before 'start'.

The base.js file also has not changed.

And in the file start.js was removed, as I said before, the applybindings and modified the first line. Now I called the Viewmodel and template by the variables that were referenced in the 'define' and the file looks like this:

**Start.js:**

```
define(['knockout', 'knockoutMapping', 'menu', 'text!assets/js/component/templates/menu.html'], function (ko, komap, menu, menuhtml) {
    ko.components.register('table_n', {
        viewModel: menu,
        template: menuhtml
    });
});
```

And with that the table was loaded correctly.